# accessing application from different computer

Tags: php, mysql, networking

I have an application created in php and using MySQL for back-end. I connect to the front-end of application on my PC by typing

```
(http://localhost:8080/my_data/login.php)
```

in the browser. the database is in my computer and php files are also in my computer. i don't know how can other users can get access to the application from the browser in their pc..i am not good with networking stuff.

Comment: others on the same network or others globally ?

Comment: they are in same network..

Comment: http: //IPOfYourMachine:8080/my_data/login.php (though this ins't best long term, you need a webserver and a place to host the db) (no space in http: ...did it to avoid auto link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am assuming Windows). At your machine at a command prompt type `ipconfig` to get your IP address:

```
specific instructions:
click windows orb, 
then type cmd  in text area
type ipconfig and press enter
line reading IPv4 Address will have an IP address x.x.x.x... use that IP address in place of localhost.
```

[image]

Assuming others on network are within the same subnet and not have vlans and what not, it should work.

a URL uses something called DNS or a hosts file to lookup that name and translate that common name to an IP address, by specifying the IP address and port, you avoid the need for the DNS, assuming the IP address is "Routable" for the users needed to access it.

Here's an example: Type `http://74.125.225.176` in a browser and you get google search!  There's a lot more to this really, but this is just the basic workings.

[image]